# Webpack error after upgrading Node: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpacker, babel-loader

I'm troubleshooting a webpack error.

Command: `bin/webpack --colors --progress`

Produces this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@flatfile/sdk/dist/index.js 351:361
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (351:361)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|           class v extends i {
|             constructor(e, t) {
>               super(e), r(this, "code", "FF-UA-00"), r(this, "name", "UnauthorizedError"), r(this, "debug", "The JWT was not signed with a recognized private key or you did not provide the necessary information to identify the end user"), r(this, "userMessage", "There was an issue establishing a secure import session."), e && (this.debug = e), this.code = t ?? "FF-UA-00";
|             }
|           }
 @ ./app/javascript/src/app/pages/content_assets/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--8-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/javascript/src/app/pages/content_assets/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&) 22:0-41 125:6-14
 @ ./app/javascript/src/app/pages/content_assets/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./app/javascript/src/app/pages/content_assets/Index.vue
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/app.js
```

**NOTES**

- I found what appears to be an identical issue reported in the Flatfile project: https://github.com/FlatFilers/sdk/issues/83

> Looks like ES2020 was emitted to the /dist folder so my cra babel loader is not able to parse it, in order to fix it I need to include the path on my webpack config.

- `Node v16.13.1`
- We're using webpack with a Rails project via the [webpacker](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html) package (`@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3"`) which is depending on `webpack@4.46.0`.
- When I change to Node v14x and rebuild node_modules (`yarn install`) webpack compiles successfully.
- The line referenced in the error (351:361) **does not exist** when I go check the file in node_modules/
- We have a yarn.lock file, which I delete and recreate before running `yarn install`. I also delete the node_modules directory to ensure a "fresh" download of the correct packages.
- We have a babel.config.js file...

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          }
        }
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ],
      ["babel-preset-typescript-vue", { "allExtensions": true, "isTSX": true }]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false,
          regenerator: true,
          corejs: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

Ultimately I want to get webpack to compile. If you had advice about any of the following questions, it would help a lot.

1. Why would changing the Node version (only) cause different webpack behavior? We aren't changing the the webpack version or the version of the @flatfile package that's causing the error.
2. Why is the error pointing to a line that doesn't exist in the package? Is this evidence of some kind of caching problem?
3. Does the workaround mentioned in the linked GitHub issue shed light on my problem?

Comment: `When I change to Node v14x and re-install the node_modules`, so you didn't **only** change node version.

Comment: @morganney I don't understand your comment. Maybe there's confusion about what I meant by "re-install the node_modules". I meant that after changing the node version I ran `yarn install`.

Comment: That clarifies a bit but things like whether you use a lock file,  have a babel config, or node_modules was deleted is still unknown. Semver in the open source community doesn't always go smoothly because for the most part the versioning is still done by people which is error prone. Anyway, your issue amounts to webpack 4 not supporting  `??` which one of your dependencies uses in it's published source code. You can add the appropriate babel plugin and then explicitly run that dependency through babel-loader in your webpack config if necessary.

Comment: @morganney I updated the notes with the additional details you requested.

`You can add the appropriate babel plugin and then explicitly run that dependency through babel-loader in your webpack config if necessary`

This sounds like exactly what I need to do. Can you point me in the right direction on how to do this? (I'm new to configuring babel / webpack)
Thanks!!

Comment: Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70036198/258174) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this.

I believe your issue is that webpack 4 does not support the nullish coalescing operator due to it's dependency on acorn 6. See this webpack [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227) and this PR [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/11221#issuecomment-672897487).

1. You haven't specified the exact minor version of Node.js 14x that worked for you. I will assume it was a version that did not fully support the nullish coalescing operator, or at least a version that `@babel/preset-env`'s `target` option understood to not support `??`, so it was transpiled by babel and thus webpack didn't complain. You can see what versions of node support nullish coalescing on [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features--nullish-coalescing-operator-----).
2. I don't fully understand the point you are making here, so not focusing on this in the proposed solution.
3. I'm not sure what the proposed workaround is in the linked issue, maybe the comment about "include the path on my webpack config", but yes the issue does seem relevant as it is pointing out the nullish coalescing operator as the source of the issue.

You can try to solve this by

- adding [`@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) to your babel config's `plugins`
- updating your webpack config to run `@flatfile/sdk` through `babel-loader` to transpile the nullish coalescing operator:

  ```js
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: filename => {
      return /node_modules/.test(filename) && !/@flatfile\/sdk\/dist/.test(filename)
    },
    use: ['babel-loader']
  }
  ```

Another possibility is to upgrade `webpacker` to a version that depends upon webpack v5.

One final remark, when you say

> We have a yarn.lock file, which I delete and recreate before running yarn install.

you probably should not be deleting the lock file before each install, as it negates the purpose of a lock file altogether.

Comment: Thanks this is super helpful!! I'm going to try this later today, but in the meantime here are a few quick responses to your questions...

Comment: `should not be deleting the lock file before each install ` I only did this between changing Node versions. I thought it made sense to let yarn find updated packages to correspond with the newer Node. Does this make sense? Maybe it makes no difference?

Comment: `2. I don't fully understand the point you are making here` The stack trace in the webpacker error points to a line (351) which does not exist in the corresponding source file if I go find it inside node_modules. The actual file only has around 100 lines of code. I find this confusing and mysterious.

Comment: `exact minor version of Node.js 14x that worked ` v14.17.3

Comment: I added `@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator` to the list of plugins in babel.config.js... and it worked!  I didn't have to touch the webpack configs at all. I actually tried configuring the loader as you instructed, but that produced a mountain of errors with this pattern: `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:38)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js`
With the original webpack configs (but the upated babel configs) it works exactly as expected. I'm confused why this worked in this way. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: It's really hard to say without having your entire setup in front of me to debug, especially with webpacker involved, but as you observed the crux of the issue was `babel-loader` not transpiling nullish coalescing operator which webpack 4 chokes on.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. My best guess is that Babel loader was already applying to node_modules... but the necessary plugin wasn't configured. I _think_ that would explain why updating babel.config.js (only) solved the issue. Does that sound plausible to you? I know it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Yep, that would be my assumption from here as well, that babel-loader was already applying to node_modules.