Failed to compile - may need additional loaders... React app
I am running a 3 y.o. React application. At first I thought it was the npm and node updates, so I downgraded both.
However, I still get this error:
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;

Any ideas, or where to start looking?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036039/react-storybook-not-running-after-installation-of-react-leaflet-version-3 (or directly https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/883). Feel free to add specific details of your toolchain if you neef further help.

Line 10, character 41 appears to be the "nullish coalescing operator" (??). This JS feature was added to ECMAScript in 2020, so if you're using a babel preset, make sure it's equal to or greater than ES2020. Alternatively, you can manually install and use the plugin for that (@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator).

I installed the plugin following your link (using npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator) This told me there were critical issues. So, I ran npm audit fix --force and this output line worries me: npm WARN audit No fix available for axios@0.8.1 - 0.27.2

ghybs's comment is the right direction for you to look next.
